# Create method that directly access tostring of object java

Tags: java, printing, system.out

We know that when we pass any object like list, map or any object to `System.out.println()`, it will get the `list.toString()`, `map.toString()`, `object.toString()`as parameter automatically.

> I want to create user defined function like this.

```java
static void print(String s)
{
    //someprocessing
}
```

But for this method when I pass any object to it should be converted explicitly to string.

for example,

- print(list.toString());

But I want to define a method that will implicitly convert object to its toString. Can anyone tell me how to do that in java ?

Comment: the method `println` does *not*  get "toString() as parameter automatically.". It simply has the method `println` overloaded for all kinds of different data types and then inside the method calls `toString` itself for the method that takes an `Object` as a parmater. You can by the way just have a look at the source code of `java.io.PrintStream` to see how it is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something Like this to solve this !

```java
static void print(Object o)
{
   System.out.println(o.toString());
   // String rep = o.toString();
}
```

> So I can use it on any Object type except for primitives.